# Assigning to a variable in a parent context in Bash

Tags: bash, variables, scope, dynamic-scope, upvar

I want to write a function similar to the `read` built-in, where I pass a variable name as an argument, and the function returns its result into the variable named.

I tried doing it like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
FIB_CALLS=0

# usage: fib $variable $index
# puts fibonacci number $index in the variable named $variable
fib() {
    (( FIB_CALLS++ ))

    local -n result="$1"
    local i="$2"
    local a
    local b

    if (( i < 2 )); then
        result="$i"
    else
        fib a $(( i - 1 ))
        fib b $(( i - 2 ))
        (( result = a + b ))
    fi
}

i=15
fib val $i
echo "fib($i) = $val"
echo "$FIB_CALLS calls to fib"
```

The above doesn’t work.  If I call `fib` with the first argument `i`, `a` or `b`, the assignment becomes to the local variable defined inside `fib`, and the caller does not receive the result at all; and of course, if I happen to name the result variable `result`, I get circular reference errors.  In effect, this leaks the implementation of `fib`.  Because I perform recursion here, I cannot just rename the variable; the variable name from level above will inevitably clash with the one at the current level.  So not even `____i_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` will work.  I cannot instead echo the result and capture it in a subshell, because I want to keep being able to modify global variables from within the function, which subshells cannot do.

Is there a way to assign to a dynamically-named variable as defined **in the context of the caller**?

In other words, I am looking for the bash equivalent of Tcl’s [`upvar`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/upvar.htm), which allows me to write this:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
variable fib_calls 0

proc fib {result_var i} {
    global fib_calls
    incr fib_calls

    upvar $result_var result

    if {$i < 2} {
        set result $i
    } else {
        fib a [expr {$i - 1}]
        fib b [expr {$i - 2}]
        set result [expr {$a + $b}]
    }
}

set i 15
fib val $i
puts "fib($i) = $val"
puts "$fib_calls calls to fib"
```

Of course this is a rather contrived example; in normal Tcl one would just use `return`.  This is just to demonstrate the principle.

(Editorial note: the example in the question was previously different.)

Comment: Related: [Circular name references in bash shell function, but not in ksh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302578/circular-name-references-in-bash-shell-function-but-not-in-ksh). I thought Bash 5 was supposed to fix that, but like Kusalananda's answer there shows, it really doesn't do it well.

Comment: just came across this item that may be of interest: [bash: passing variables by reference](https://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference) which includes a [set of bash functions to implement upvar() and upvars()](https://www.fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Passing_variables_by_reference#Appendix_A:_upvars.sh)

Comment: That’s not really `upvar`; the Tcl primitive creates a nameref to the variable in the parent dynamic scope. Though it’s an interesting resource nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** following is in response to the newly updated question (as of 5 Nov 2022) ...

Since OP has ruled out the use of subproces calls (`x=$((fib ...))`), and assuming OP is not open to a different algorithm (eg, this [array based solution](http://www.binaryphile.com/bash/2018/10/29/approach-bash-like-a-developer-part-35-recursion.html)) or a different language (eg, `c++`, `awk`, `perl`, etc), this leaves us with trying to devise a (convoluted?) approach in `bash` ...

As I see it each invocation of the `fib()` function needs the ability to update the 'global' variable at the parent level while at the same time needing to maintain a separate 'local' version of the variable (which in turn becomes the 'global' variable for the child `fib()` calls).

One approach would be to dynamically generate new variable names in each invocation of the `fib()` function.  The key issue will be to insure each new variable name is unique:

- `uuid` or `uuidgen` would be ideal but would require a subprocess call (not allowed per OP's rules) in order to capture the output (eg, `new_var_name=var_$(uuidgen)`)
- `$RANDOM` is not very 'random'; in unit testing it's not uncommon to generate duplicates within a batch of 1000 references; since OP's `fib(15)` algorithm will require a few thousand `$RANDOM` calls this is a non-starter
- if running `bash 5.1+` the new `$SRANDOM` would serve this purpose well
- or we can just piggyback off a variable we know has a different value on each call to `fib()` (eg, `$FIB_CALLS`)

Making a few changes to OP's current code:

```
fib() {
    (( FIB_CALLS++ ))

    # for all local variables we assume a '_' prefix is sufficient to escape conflicts (otherwise pick a different prefix)

    local -n _result=$1
    local    _i="$2"

    # if using bash 5.1+ we can make use of $SRANDOM
    # local -n _a=var_$SRANDOM             # use a nameref to associate local variable '_a' with a new random variable name
    # local -n _b=var_$SRANDOM             # use a nameref to associate local variable '_b' with a new random variable name

    # if bash 5.1+ is not available we can make use of $FIB_CALLS
    local -n _a=var_a_${FIB_CALLS}         # use a nameref to associate local variable '_a' with a new random variable name
    local -n _b=var_b_${FIB_CALLS}         # use a nameref to associate local variable '_b' with a new random variable name

    if (( "$_i" < 2 ))
    then
        _result="$_i"
    else
        fib ${!_a} $(( _i -1 ))            # instead of passing '_a' we pass the associated nameref ('var_$SRANDOM')
        fib ${!_b} $(( _i -2 ))            # instead of passing '_b' we pass the associated nameref ('var_$SRANDOM')
        (( _result = _a + _b ))
    fi

    unset ${!_a} ${!_b}                    # release memory
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
FIB_CALLS=0
i=15
fib val $i
echo "fib($i) = $val"
echo "$FIB_CALLS calls to fib"
```

This generates:

```
fib(15) = 610
1973 calls to fib
```

**NOTES:**

- see [fiddle](https://jdoodle.com/ia/yL5) (using `$SRANDOM` to create new variable names)
- see [fiddle](https://jdoodle.com/ia/yLa) (using `$FIB_CALLS` to create new variable names)
- for `fib(15)` we end up generating/populating 3900+ variables; memory usage in this case will be negligible; for excessively large `fib(X)` calls where memory usage becomes an issue it would make (more) sense to look at a new algorithm or use a different language

---

While this is an interesting technical exercise I wouldn't recommend this solution (or any solution based on this algorithm) for a production environment.

For a `fib(15)` calculation:

- this highly-redundant algorithm (recursively calculating previous fibs) requires 1973 calls of the `fib()` function
- a tail-recursion algorithm (building fibs from 0/1 to desired final fib) would require 15 `fib()` function calls as well as eliminate the need to dynamically generate new variables on each pass through the `fib()` function
- a simple looping construct (building fibs from 0/1 to desired final fib) will perform about the same as a tail-recursion algorithm but without the overhead of maintaining the recursion stack
- each of these algorithms (highly-redundant, tail-recursion, simple-loop) will run faster in a more appropriate language (eg, `perl`, `python`, `awk`, etc)

Comment: `$(uuidgen)` would have been fine actually, if wasteful (I only wanted to avoid subshells because I wanted to write to globals from recursive invocations). I guess this is still a `DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` solution, and it leaks memory a lot (see `declare -p` after the loop); though the latter can be avoided by writing `local __x=__x_${SRANDOM}; local "${__x}"` and then using `${__x}` and `${!__x}` instead of `__x` and `${__x}` everywhere. But other than that, I think I like this one the most. And yes, I know the algorithm is awfully inefficient, it’s only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: my (bigger) concern with `$(uuidgen)` was the overhead of spawning 1973 subprocesses ... unless we're looking for ways to make this implementation even *more* inefficient!   as for the memory usage/leak I've opted to leave the answer as is and just add an `unset` at the end; might be of interest if you post an answer with your final improvements

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to assign to a dynamically-named variable as defined in the context of the caller?

Once a variable is defined as `local` in the current context, there's no builtin that allows you to modify it in the parent context directly. The intuitive solution of using `declare -g "$varname"=...` doesn't work, as it reaches the global context (not the parent one).

There's a work-around though. The following example illustrates the method, and shows that calling `unset` directly doesn't work (is it a bug?), you need to wrap `unset` in a function:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

funset() { unset "$@"; }

myfun1() { local "$1";  unset "$1"; printf -v "$1" %s 'myfun1'; }
myfun2() { local "$1"; funset "$1"; printf -v "$1" %s 'myfun2'; }

var=global; echo "$var"
myfun1 var; echo "$var"
myfun2 var; echo "$var"
```

```
global
global
myfun2
```

---

For your recursive `fib` and most nameref-functions, you can just use conditional declarations and make sure to address the arguments as `$1 $2 ...`, **that avoids any possible name clash and doesn't leak any unwanted variable**:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FIB_CALLS=0

# fib varname integer
fib() {

    (( FIB_CALLS++ ))

    [[ $1 != a ]] && local a
    [[ $1 != b ]] && local b

    if (( $2 < 2 ))
    then
        (( $1 = $2 ))
    else
        fib a "$(( $2 - 1 ))"
        fib b "$(( $2 - 2 ))"
        (( $1 = a + b ))
    fi
}

b=15
fib a "$b"

echo "fib($b) = $a"
echo "$FIB_CALLS calls to fib"
```

```
fib(15) = 610
1973 calls to fib
```

**remarks:** Please notice that you can now use ANY variable name as first argument of `fib`, even `a` and `b` (which at some point in the recursion will be locally defined in `fib`). You can also see that the global variable `b` keeps its prior value after the call to `fib`.

Comment: The first trick seems too obscure for my taste, and it seems neither of the two is applicable to recursion in full generality, only in particular circumstances that my `fib` just happens to luckily satisfy (I don’t need to preserve the initial value of the ‘upper’ variable, I can write out the result only at the end). Points for creativity, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the constraints for the target function outlined in the question are as follows:

1. Assigning a value to a dynamically-named variable in a parent context;
2. Using function scope variable name as parameter for recursion;
3. Modifying global variable.

The initial OP's implementation coupled with advices to resolve constraint #2 revealed the "circular name reference" problem. Let's not correct the initial implementation, but change the idea of the variables by adding another parent level. And use this [local builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-local) feature:

> it makes the variable name have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.

```
GLOBAL_VAR=0
INDENT="          "
CALL_LEVEL=0

foo() {
  ((CALL_LEVEL++))
  echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}foo START: var = $var; dynamically_named_var = $dynamically_named_var" 
  local result=0
  while [ $GLOBAL_VAR -lt 3 ]; do
    (( GLOBAL_VAR++ ))
    (( var-- ))
    echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}Recursive function call #$GLOBAL_VAR"
    foo var
  done
  result=$(( $GLOBAL_VAR + $var ))
  var=$result
  echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}foo END: var = $var; dynamically_named_var = $dynamically_named_var"
  ((CALL_LEVEL--))
}

runFoo() {
  ((CALL_LEVEL++))
  local -n var=$1
  echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}runFoo START: var = $var; GLOBAL_VAR = $GLOBAL_VAR"
  foo var
  echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}runFoo END: var = $var; GLOBAL_VAR = $GLOBAL_VAR"
  ((CALL_LEVEL--))
}

dynamically_named_var=10
echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}GLOBAL context: GLOBAL_VAR = $GLOBAL_VAR; dynamically_named_var = $dynamically_named_var"
runFoo dynamically_named_var
echo "${INDENT:0:(($CALL_LEVEL*2))}GLOBAL context: GLOBAL_VAR = $GLOBAL_VAR; dynamically_named_var = $dynamically_named_var"
```

Output:

```
GLOBAL context: GLOBAL_VAR = 0; dynamically_named_var = 10
  runFoo START: var = 10; GLOBAL_VAR = 0
    foo START: var = 10; dynamically_named_var = 10
    Recursive function call #1
      foo START: var = 9; dynamically_named_var = 9
      Recursive function call #2
        foo START: var = 8; dynamically_named_var = 8
        Recursive function call #3
          foo START: var = 7; dynamically_named_var = 7
          foo END: var = 10; dynamically_named_var = 10
        foo END: var = 13; dynamically_named_var = 13
      foo END: var = 16; dynamically_named_var = 16
    foo END: var = 19; dynamically_named_var = 19
  runFoo END: var = 19; GLOBAL_VAR = 3
GLOBAL context: GLOBAL_VAR = 3; dynamically_named_var = 19
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you'll end up with something like:

```
foo() {
    local result
    result="some computation with $1"
    echo "$result"
}

thing=$(set -eu; foo)
```

Comment: I specifically said that I don’t want to use a subshell.

Answer (score -1):

Nameref combined with indirect variable (by `!`) should achieve what you wanted :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

recursive(){
    declare -n not_used_by_caller_name=$1
    local      not_used_by_caller_level=${2-0} # This is just for controlling recursion
    test $not_used_by_caller_level -lt 3 || return
    # ${!not_used_by_caller_name} passes `var` to next level
    recursive ${!not_used_by_caller_name} $((not_used_by_caller_level+1))
    not_used_by_caller_name=$(( (not_used_by_caller_level+1) ** 3 ))
    printf "Level %s returning %2d, var=%2d\n"\
        $not_used_by_caller_level $not_used_by_caller_name $var
}
recursive var
echo "Final value $var"
```

All assignments to `not_used_by_caller_name` assign to variable `var`

Output :

```
Level 2 returning 27, var=27
Level 1 returning  8, var= 8
Level 0 returning  1, var= 1
Final value 1
```

fib version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fib(){
    declare -n unused_identifier_array=$1
    local unused_identifier_nth=$2
    if  test $unused_identifier_nth -lt ${#unused_identifier_array}; then
        return # As already calculated
    fi
    if  test $unused_identifier_nth -lt 2; then
        unused_identifier_array[unused_identifier_nth]=$unused_identifier_nth
        return
    fi
    fib ${!unused_identifier_array} $((unused_identifier_nth-2))
    fib ${!unused_identifier_array} $((unused_identifier_nth-1))
    unused_identifier_array[unused_identifier_nth]=$((
        unused_identifier_array[unused_identifier_nth-2]
       +unused_identifier_array[unused_identifier_nth-1]))
}

declare -a sequence
fib sequence 15
declare -p sequence
# Output :
# declare -a sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2" [4]="3" [5]="5" [6]="8" [7]="13" [8]="21" [9]="34" [10]="55" [11]="89" [12]="144" [13]="233" [14]="377" [15]="610")
```

Comment: So how would you rewrite `fib`?

Comment: @user3840170 Rewritten